# F# script can't find nuget package - probably because multiple package sources defined

Tags: f#

create an FSharp fsx script, type this:

```
#r "nuget: FSharp.Data"
```

get

```
Error   FS3217  ...: error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/.../index.json.   F# Miscellaneous Files  ...\Script.fsx  1   Active
```

I suspect this is because i have a custom Nuget source defined in addition to nuget.org, is there a way I can force the script to just look in a nuget.org?

I find the nuget client configuration at best confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using visual studio 2022

I fixed it by disabling the other sources

Tools->Manage Packages for solution-> package source setting icon

disable the ones you don't want

RESTART visual studio

then it will work

it would be nice if you could specify the package source in the script, i find nuget config a bit of a black art, and I'd rather control explicitly in the script that have to change config (which i will inevitably change back and forget)

Comment: You can specify a source in the script with `#i "nuget: https://..."`. But I don't think it completely overrides the ones in your global config, it just adds one.